# Mysql Insert Select Common Phrase into new table

Tags: mysql

I have a Table which with many rows and looks like something below.

```
id       Name
1481    Carrier_186_CLI 
1469    Carrier_186_OUT
1480    Carrier_107_CLI
1483    Carrier_107_OUT
```

All i want is to copy the rows into another table which has the common phrase , like

```
id       Name
1       Carrier_186
2       Carrier_107
```

I tried this

```
Insert into newtable(Name)select Name from oldtable group by Name
```

I know it wont work but i am unable to find a solution for this. I am new to mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use string function [`substring_index`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to pick value before 2nd underscore

```
Insert into newtable(Name)
select substring_index(Name,'_',2) 
from oldtable 
group by substring_index(Name,'_',2)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57f484)

Comment: Perfectly Perfect Bro :)